# indexOf in HTML with min length

Tags: html

I have some element  containes alphabates & number as input example :- 12EDFG3456 , 73WERTY1234 etc.
All these elements starts with number and then contains some alphabates + Number.
In HTML , while creating frontend, we have used minLength method which will check first , the length of these elements which is fine.
I am trying to keep one more check where we are making sure elements start with Numbers.

Can we use index (to check index place 0 ) and check if it is number , if yes then check minLengh and so on.?

```
<mat-label> element  </mat-label>
<input matInput minlength ="10" maxlength ="12" name= "traNum formControlName ="traNum">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [“pattern”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/pattern) attribute, like so:

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" minlength="10" maxlength="12" pattern="[0-9].+">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```